# Storyboard tabBar not tinted

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

I'm developing a iOS app for iPhone. The app is all wrapped in a Tab Bar Controller (#0), also, each tab is wrapped in a Navigation Controller.

I have 4 views (#1, #2, #3, #4) for each one of the tabs, all of them are working perfectly fine. But when I see those views in the storyboard, two of the views (#3, #4) don't have the tab bar tinted correctly. I don't know what this can be due to, any help?

[image: Storyboard]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen if your *simulated metrics* in storyboard is not in *inferred state*.

[image]

Hope this helps.